# Firestore OR query improvement

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a social network app.
I need to query the last `Post`s ordered by date from any people that i follow.

My working query so far is :

```
Query getRecentFriendsPost(List<String> followings, int postedDate) {
    return getUsersCollection()
        .where("uid", whereIn: followings)
        .where("postedAt", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: postedDate)
        .orderBy("dateCreated", descending: true)
        .limit(16);
  }
```

This doesn't answer my needs unfortunately.
The `followings` list contains the userIDs that i follow, and the length can grow until thousands. Firestore support only 10 items in `whereIn` clause.

Second problem, if the length is 1000, it will cost 100x10 queries to split the `followings` list into block of 10 uids.

This is very expensive and slow.

I must use the whole `followings` list to be sure to not miss the most recents posts.

How can i perform such a query with Firestore ?
The `followings` list allows me to query the `User` object associated to the `Post`, if a `Post` is retrieved by the query.

Should i go for `RealTime Database` in such situation ? (If i should even keep `Firebase` products)

I did not find a better architecture either, if anyone knows how to improve this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: ... Would it not be easier to use Pub/Sub to handle subscriptions like this? As in, an on-demand subscription on pub/sub that gets called for the user when they use your app. Is there a reason you want to do this specifically with firebase?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No there is no specific reason, i was just asking if there was a way using it to reduce costs / improve performance, maybe by an architecture refactor... 
i am open to new solutions as well that answer my needs. 
i took a look at Pub/Sub, performances would be improved but not the pricing. 
My goal is to make a really basic "Instagram-feed-like" (without AI / no aggregation based on likes / seen posts....).

Comment: Then I guess it really depends... Is this for a single user? Or is it a whole network of interconnected users, because I'm afraid my answer will vary according to which.

Comment: I am focusing on what a single specific user should see, which directly connected to the users he is following and the presence of a publication for any people he is following within the delta of time between 2 application openings. publications (posts) should be ordered by date, even if a following has posted several posts (to simplify) since the last time the current user has opened the app.
I am all ears for a solution with a whole network of interconnected users but maybe in private tchat, this question is really about 1 specific user. Thank you again !

Comment: then I most definitely recommend using Pub/Sub over Firestore. Because to do this kind of thing for Firestore I believe you would need custom indexes, one for each user that includes all their subscriptions, and there is a [max limit on indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits)... So yeah, for a chat though? A chat could work in Firestore, and with Firebase's options you could use Messages to notify someone of new, well, messages in their inbox. Pub/Sub is good for RSS-like feeds, one-to-one chats can work in firestore, in short.

Comment: Thank you for your advice i will take a better look then at Pub/Sub. Yes indeed the limit is 200 i could not make it with custom indexes... I also have a chat in my app and using Firestore for this without issues.

Comment: Chats would work fine since it's only between two people so there's no joining required. Please do be so kind as to post the solution you end up choosing in an answer to your own post and select it, that way this post will be more visible to those looking for it (or something like it) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have migrated my database to `MongoDB` and i am able to do so in one query.

Performances are not impacted before passing an array of 6000 values, after that it starts giving results in more than 100ms which remains perfectly fine for my use case.